# How to execute commands from standard output?

Tags: linux, shell

I have a python script that print many commands if I execute `python aaa.py`:

```
(base)  tkl@TKL ~/Desktop python aaa.py
cp chart.xls ./me/chart.xls
find . | grep bro
scp -r fefe@192.168.1.4:/data/ti.exe .
```

Now I'm wondering if there's some linux command to execute these output as command sequencely and print all the output in the same shell, what I'm imaging is like that:

`python aaa.py | xargs -i execute {}`

Does such 'execute' exist?

Comment: [How to find list of available shells by command-line?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/140286/7167)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bash` is the normal processor to execute a bunch of shell commands. Like this:

```
{ echo date; echo ls; } | bash
```

So you could do this, if you trust your Python not to emit any *"Bad Stuff"* ™️

```
python aaa.py | bash
```

Or, similarly, as suggested in the comments, you may specifically mean a POSIX shell, or `sh`, in which case:

```
python aaa.py | sh
```

Comment: Perhaps in this case, it is `... | sh`, because the OP does not use bash.

Comment: @user1934428 I missed that. How did you deduce it, please?

Comment: The OP tagged the question just by _shell_, which means POSIX shell. In the question, just "shell" in general is used, not, i.e., zsh. Further, the example code given would work fine in POSIX shell. Taken together, it is safe to assume that _sh_ is intended.

Comment: @user1934428 I don't tend to assume that tags are perfectly set or that they indicate a cast-iron preference or specification. Many users just tag with `shell` and don't bother drilling down to which one they mean specifically, or don't know or care. Thanks for your suggestion - I will add it into my answer so that those who do care can see it better.

Comment: You are right, just that in this case, the tags went well with the question, and if `sh` is sufficient for the answer, this should be used. Some people still try to do as much as possible in the `sh`-realm, perhaps for compatibility or speed.